# Different behavior for qualified name lookup with using-directive when making namespace inline

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, name-lookup, using-directives

I am learning using-directives, and trying to understand the name lookup rules for using-directive, but I encountered this problem and I cannot found any explanation.

The problem looks like this:

**prog1**: namespace `C` is outside of namespace `A`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
namespace C
{
    namespace Detail
    {
        void func()
        {
            std::cout << "C::Detail::func " << "\n";
        }
    }
}

namespace A
{
    namespace Detail
    {
        void func()
        {
            std::cout << "A::Detail::func " << "\n";
        }
    }

    using namespace C;

    void func2()
    {
        Detail::func();  // no conflict, select A::Detail::func
    }
}

int main()
{
    A::func2();
    return 0;
}
```

The program succeeds, executes and outputs `A::Detail::func`.

When I move `namespace C` inside of `namespace A`, there is a compiler error:

**prog2**: namespace `C` is inside of namespace `A`:

```cpp
namespace A
{
    namespace C
    {
        namespace Detail
        {
            void func()
            {
                std::cout << "C::Detail::func " << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    namespace Detail
    {
        void func()
        {
            std::cout << "A::Detail::func " << "\n";
        }
    }

    using namespace C;

    void func2()
    {
        Detail::func();    // conflict for A::Detail::func and A::C::Detail::func
    }
}

int main()
{
    A::func2();
    return 0;
}
```

The program has this compiler error:

```
prog.cc:27:9: error: reference to 'Detail' is ambiguous
        Detail::func();
        ^
prog.cc:15:15: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'A::Detail'
    namespace Detail
              ^
prog.cc:6:19: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'A::C::Detail'
        namespace Detail
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Compiler: GCC 9.3.0 and CLANG 9.0.0, both have the same result.

My question:

Why are the results different, and what is the specific rule for qualified name lookup in this scenario?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I edited the title and the question to make it slightly clearer. Please let me know if this changes the meaning of your question in any way. Also, since you asked for a specific rule, you might consider adding the [tag:language-lawyer] tag to the question. If you do that, then you'll need to remove one of the other tags. You can remove any of them, they're all equally applicable, except the c++ tag of course :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[namespace.udir]/2** A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive*. During unqualified name lookup (6.4.1), the names appear **as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace** which contains both the *using-directive* and the nominated namespace. [ *Note:* In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”. *—end note* ]

Emphasis mine. In **prog1**, that nearest enclosing namespace is the global namespace, and `A::Detail` is found before `::Detail`. In **prog2**, that nearest enclosing namespace is `A`, and so the name lookup finds two different namespaces both named `A::Detail`.

Comment: This rule is apply for unqualified name lookup, but A::Detail is a qualified name.

Comment: `A::Detail` doesn't appear in the code shown, except within a string literal. An unqualified name lookup is indeed performed for the name `Detail` that appears in `Detail::func()`

Comment: sorry, I mean `Detail::func` is a qualified name, not `A::Detail`. This rule only for the unqualified name.

Comment: That's true, as far as it goes. But before the name `Detail::func` can be resolved via a qualified name lookup, the name `Detail` must be resolved via an unqualified name lookup. That's where the ambiguity arises. Read the error message carefully: `prog.cc:27:9: error: reference to 'Detail' is ambiguous`. Reference to `Detail`, not `Detail::func`